# Accessing instance data in Vue from Controller or Components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm using the Vue controller to update the content on my SPA. While I can import views and controllers and display them accordingly, I'm having a hard time updating some variables defined in the main Vue instance. I also tried to define them in the main view but I still cannot update them.

Here's my Vue instance:

```
new Vue({
    router,
    render: h => h(App),
    data: () => {
        return {
            showYesOrNo: false,
            showMultiChoice: false
        }
    }
}).$mount('#app')
```

This is my main view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  import ContactContainer from "./views/ContactContainer.vue"
  export default {
    name: "app",
    components:{
      ContactContainer
    },
    data: () => {
      return { // Redefined the variables here to see if I could access them in some way
        showYesOrNo: false,
        showMultiChoice: false
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="container">
       <div id="main_container">
          <transition name="fade"><router-view name="YesOrNo" v-show="!showMultiChoice"/></transition>
          <transition name="fade"><router-view name="MultiChoice" v-show="!showYesOrNo"/></transition>
          <transition name="fade"><ContactContainer name="Contact" v-show="!showMultiChoice && !showYesOrNo"></ContactContainer></transition>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Now this is how I try to access the *ShowYesOrNo* and *ShowMultiChoice* variables. First in the controller:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/YesOrNo',
    components: {
      YesOrNo: YesOrNoVue,
      MultiChoice: MultiChoiceContainer
    },
    beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
      console.log(this); //undefined
      console.log(this.$parent.showYesOrNo) //undefined
      console.log(vm.showYesOrNo) //undefined
      next();
    }
  }
]
```

Then in the *YesOrNo* vue:

```
<template>
 <!-- Some HTML -->
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function(){
    return {
      name: 'YesOrNoVue'
    }
  },
  created: function(){
    console.log(this.showYesOrNo); //undefined
    console.log(vm.showYesOrNo); //undefined
  }
}
</script>
```

I'm a little confused with the visibility of these variables so I'd like to know what's the best approach to change them when the router-view is updated (i.e. when the vue is created).

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you are familiar with using Props to pass data from parent to child, and Custom Events to pass data from child to parent.  If not, I suggest reading about Vue props and events in the docs. Also, here is an article that I found with a quick search and skimmed, that seems to explain the process: [Props down and Events up](https://medium.com/quick-code/vue-communication-patterns-an-intro-to-props-down-and-events-up-pattern-d53340d2c94)